# unordered list items with divs not inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists, display

I can't figure out how I would make this list have the items inline. The problem that arises too is that divs with class card need to be blocks but they go to a new line.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="cards">
  <li>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/static/images/card-1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <h4><b>Connect with your elevator easily</b></h4>
        <p>Shop from your trusted elevator just with few simple clicks at any point in time of your day!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/static/images/card-1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <h4><b>Connect with your elevator easily</b></h4>
        <p>Shop from your trusted elevator just with few simple clicks at any point in time of your day!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="/static/images/card-1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <h4><b>Connect with your elevator easily</b></h4>
        <p>Shop from your trusted elevator just with few simple clicks at any point in time of your day!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.cards ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cards li{
    display: inline;
}

.card {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
    padding: 1px 8px;
}
```

If I use this code the card will go into a new line, but I need them to be in the same horizontal line

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal line? On the right of the img?

Comment: Maybe try setting the container to `display: flex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display: flex; will allow you to place block or inline elements in a row and will also give you the ability to align these elements in many different ways depending on the flex-directions axis.

Read more about flex here: [Flexbox ~ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.cards ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.card img {    
    width: 60%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

h4 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cards">
  <li>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgtGOC5VrftlEBp2w-Hw1JiauZTk4jBe4JLg&usqp=CAU">
      <div class="container">
        <h4><strong>Connect with your elevator easily</strong></h4>
        <p>Shop from your trusted elevator just with few simple clicks at any point in time of your day!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgtGOC5VrftlEBp2w-Hw1JiauZTk4jBe4JLg&usqp=CAU">
      <div class="container">
        <h4><strong>Connect with your elevator easily</strong></h4>
        <p>Shop from your trusted elevator just with few simple clicks at any point in time of your day!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgtGOC5VrftlEBp2w-Hw1JiauZTk4jBe4JLg&usqp=CAU">
      <div class="container">
        <h4><strong>Connect with your elevator easily</strong></h4>
        <p>Shop from your trusted elevator just with few simple clicks at any point in time of your day!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```